# Can we integrate TFS with Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: xamarin, tfs, version-control, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac

I am using Visual Studio Community version 7.3.3 for MacBook. I am working on a project where the repository is hosted in Team Foundation Server (TFS). Can I integrate that using the Version Control option in Visual Studio. Git and SVN are possible thats what I heard. But need some help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requirement is under plan now. Please check [this uservoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/563332-visual-studio-for-mac/suggestions/17136163-tfs-version-control):

> We’ve been working on some technical prototypes to see how we could
>   best connect to TFS from a Mac and at this point I’m happy to say that
>   this work is now planned for an upcoming release. Please keep an eye
>   on this site for updates!

Answer (score 0):

As of now TFS integration is not implemented for Visual Studio in Mac, they are working on that. Got this information from one person who is directly involved in the development of Xamarin for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Link](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/563332-visual-studio-for-mac/suggestions/17136163-tfs-version-control?tracking_code=2113ba4fb49da9bfcd00ab714d40d714) this feature is now officially supported and deployed with the new version Visual Studio for Mac (extension v0.3)